# Website is not scrolling on Windows Touch Devices

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, scroll, touch

I've developed a one-page website using Bootstrap. http://cpproject.co.uk/social2/

The website works totally fine on all other devices, responsive and also you can scroll.

However, you can't scroll using the touch screen on Windows Devices and Laptops which have touch screen and using the IE Browser. (Works fine on Chrome on a Touch Laptop)

I can't find anything similar to this. I would really appreciate any help or fixes.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your link «can't be reached. cpclients.co.uk’s server DNS address could not be found.»

Comment: Oops! Thanks for letting me know. I've corrected the URL. It's http://cpproject.co.uk/social2/ @LouysPatriceBessette